# When to RPC/REST GET/POST?

Tags: rest, post, get, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'm working on my first Apigility project, and the documentation isn't quite lining up with our previous developers' ways of doing things, so I'm a little confused on how I should be doing some things (some of which also don't seem to fit in quite with Apigility's 'preferred' way of doing things).

For instance, I'm trying to set up an endpoint that takes 5 required vars/values where the first is an "ID" but goes to a 3rd-party data source where the other params are for different tables than the ID is for (so say 2 params go to a 2nd table and the other 2 params go to a 3rd table).

So, I can't just set up the endpoint to be like "/the/info[/:id]", it needs all 5 params passed where I just take those params and submit them to the 3rd party data source and get back some data that I format for the response to our user's front-end UI.

I've been playing around and Apigility seems very picky on how things should be, so I'm confused on whether this fits better a REST or RPC with a GET or POST request... I'd prefer the values not be sent through the URL (which is through an https-encrypted AJAX call anyways), but barring that I'm just not sure which formats this should be for (nevermind whether to use a Mapper or a Service with the Resource).

Answer (score 2):

Here I give a short analogic when do we should use `RPC` or `REST`.

**REST** stands for **Representational State Transfer** advocates that web applications use HTTP as it was originally envisioned. Lookups should use *GET* requests. *PUT*/*PATCH*, *POST*, and *DELETE* requests should be used for creation, mutation, and deletion. *REST API Resource usually is noun*, and this REST usage identically with *CRUD*

Example:

We wanna create API Resource for `Book` object. And this resource purposed for `Book` *CRUD*. So, we can choose this method (REST) to create the API Resource.
It mean the api will be access like this

```
GET     http://example.com/api/v1/book
GET     http://example.com/api/v1/book/1
POST    http://example.com/api/v1/book
PATCH   http://example.com/api/v1/book/1
DELETE  http://example.com/api/v1/book/1
```

Can we use additional parameters in url in REST like this `https://example.com/api/v1/book/?param1=1&param2=2`?

Yes we can! Usually we used additional params for `filtering` and `sorting` `GET` result. But it open for another purposed. Please check this documentation, in `collection_query_whitelist` sub-key.
https://apigility.org/documentation/modules/zf-rest#name=user-configuration

**RPC** stands for **Remote Procedure Call**. And in Apigility, it mean RPC web services. *RPC API Resource usually is verb*, like a function name. And we can freely use HTTP Method for this RPC (not like REST, the HTTP method describe the operation).

Example:

We wanna create API Resouce for `User` Registration. This resource purposed for create new user to database, but we don't need CRUD operation to `User` object. And for this case, choosing RPC is more appropriate than REST in Apigility. So, we can create a RPC resource with name `register` and use `POST` HTTP Method.

```
POST https://example.com/api/v1/register
```

I hope this short analogic can help you to understand the difference between REST and RPC, and when to use them.